# Error en el request desde angular hacia servicio hecho con symfony

Tags: typescript, angular

Cuando hago mi solicitud post desde angular hacia servicio hecho con symfony, me responde que existe error en el request, también en el grant_type, (uso oauth 2.0 en la autenticación), he encontrado post donde me dice que las configuracion de oauth 2.0 se envían en el body y que le coloque los headers respectivos. Así hago el post:

```
public autenticar(usuario:any) {

let uriUsuario:string = "http://uriLogin";

let data = JSON.stringify(usuario);

let headers = new Headers(
  {
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept':'application/json'
  }
);  

this.http.post(uriUsuario, data, {headers: headers}).subscribe(res => {
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/main']);
}, error => {
  console.log(error.text());
})
```

}

El erro literal es:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Dale una mirada a esta respuesta [Check the “grant_type” parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37607443/3590533) a ver si te puede ayudar.

Comment: Gracias amigo, mi solución la encontré en este post: http://www.baeldung.com/angular-4-upgrade-for-spring-security-oauth/